# ¿Como puedo parsear mas objetos que tengo dentro de arrays en JSON y kotln?

Tags: android-studio, json, kotlin

> Cita en bloque Lo que quiero es para no repterir codigo pueda jalar los datos sin hacer array, array1 etc ¿como lo puedo hacer?

```
val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_DATA, Response.Listener { response ->
        progressDialog.dismiss()

        try {

            val jsonObject = JSONObject(response)

            val array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("VXM_POP_ESPANOL_ENERGIZANTE")
            val array1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("VXM_POP_ESPANOL_FESTIVO")

            for (i in 0 until array.length()) {

                val jo = array.getJSONObject(i)

                val developers = DeveloperList(jo.getString("song_id"), jo.getString("song_time"), jo.getString("song_name"))
                developersLists!!.add(developers)

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacer ciclos anidados

```
val grupos = arrayOf("VXM_POP_ESPANOL_ENERGIZANTE", "VXM_POP_ESPANOL_FESTIVO")

for (i in 0 until grupos.length()) {
    val array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(grupos[i])
    for (j in 0 until array.length()) {
            val jo = array.getJSONObject(j)
            val developers = DeveloperList(jo.getString("song_id"), jo.getString("song_time"), jo.getString("song_name"))
            developersLists!!.add(developers)
        }
```